# will_paginate -> How to change the default url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

will_paginate plugin aways generates the pagination to the current url appending the *page* parameter.

Is there a way to change this? I need it to paginate to another controller/action plus some arguments.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
will_paginate(@collection, :params => { :controller => "articles", :action => "paginate" })
```